# Automated testing of Coredata iOS app on simulator with different db states

Tags: iphone, testing, core-data

I am developing an iOS app and would like to test one particular method with different database states. I think I can input information into Coredata's sqlite database correctly but I'm not sure how to then go about calling the method I want to test without having to manually run the simulator and navigate to the view in my app which calls the method.

I was planning on using Python to generate the test data and input the values into the database though I can change that if it seems unlikely to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to call an Objective-C method that will save some test objets in your base. This way you don't have to worry about the SQL structure.